# why does this inequality hold with expectations of supremums

Tags: probability, inequality

I'm reading a proof on criterion for a class to be Glivenko-Cantelli and I don't see why this holds?

$$E \sup_{g\in G} \left|E\left[
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(g(X'_i)-g(X_i))\big|X_1^n\right]\right| \leq EE \left[ \sup_{g\in G} \left| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(g(X'_i)-g(X_i)) \right| \big| X_1^n \right]
$$

http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/2013spring-stat210b/notes/8notes.pdf

Look at the 17th slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For every collection $\Xi$ of integrable random variables such that $\eta=\sup\{\xi\mid\xi\in\Xi\}$ is integrable, one has $\xi\leqslant\eta$ for every $\xi$ in $\Xi$, hence $E[\xi]\leqslant E[\eta]$ for every $\xi$ in $\Xi$, which is equivalent to 
$$\sup\limits_{\xi\in\Xi}E[\xi]\leqslant E[\eta]=E\left[\sup\limits_{\xi\in\Xi}\xi\right].$$
Can you adapt this idea to your setting?

Comment: Awesome, I finally figured it out. I wasn't using $|EZ|\leq E|Z|$.